# Bootstrap: Getting an image to resize to 100% height in uneven 2 column layout

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/dq5T5/

The fiddle above shows the problem.

Since the row has a white background, there ends up being empty space under the image when the browser window is resized.

I just want the image to fill the entire height of the left column, but I also need it to stack vertically as it currently does (responsive).

```
<body>
    <div class="widereport">
        <div class="col-md-4 no-gutters">
            <figure class="animated-overlay overlay-alt">
                <img class="img-responsive" width="640" height="400" alt="img alt" src="http://placehold.it/600x450" itemprop="image">
                <a title="image" href="/"></a>
                <figcaption>
                    <div class="thumb-info thumb-info-alt">
                        <i class="ss-navigateright"></i>
                    </div>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h5 class="portfolio-subtitle" itemprop="alternativeHeadline">mini menta | March     2014</h5>
            <h3 class="portfolio-item-title mt0" itemprop="name headline">
                Title here
            </h3>
            <p class="itemdeets">85 Pages</p>
            <div class="portfolio-item-excerpt" itemprop="description">
                <p class="mb9">Sed non orci sed ante dignissim aliquam. Fusce in sapien leo. Praesent justo nibh, dapibus eu fermentum sit amet, rutrum sit amet nunc. Aliquam augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in fauc ibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer in enim dui. Suspendisse potenti. Sed placerat pellentesque nibh ut varius. Morbi aliquet nulla at sem consequat eleifend. Sed non orci sed ante dignissim aliquam. Fusce in sapien leo. Praesent justo nibh, dapibus eu fermentum sit amet, rutrum sit amet nunc. Aliquam augue. Sed placerat pellentesque nibh ut varius. Morbi aliquet nulla at sem consequat eleifend. Sed placerat pellentesque nibh ut varius. Morbi aliquet nulla at sem consequat eleifend. Sed placerat pellentesque nibh ut varius. Morbi aliquet nulla at sem consequat eleifend.</p>
            </div>
            <p>
                <span class="text pull-right mb9">More Information</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below in the class for `img-responsive` in the CSS:

```
.img-responsive {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dq5T5/2/)

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. When I scale the window down, there is still space below. I feel like the answer might involve getting rid of the col containers and using float left on the image and float right on the content, with some media queries to stack it, but I'm just stuck.